# In Sublime Text 2, is it possible to remap space space to save in vintage mode?

Tags: sublime-text-2, remapping

I've been attempting to recreate my Vim setup in Sublime Text 2.  One of the commands I most want to get working is to map space + space to save in normal/command mode.  In Vim I have this keybinding:

```
no <space><space> :wa<cr>
```

In Sublime I've tried several things without success:

```
{ "keys": [" ", " "], "command": "save" }
```

and

```
{ "keys": [" ", " "], "command": "save",
    "context":
    [
        { "key": "setting.command_mode", "operand": false },
        { "key": "setting.is_widget", "operand": false },
        { "key": "setting.vintage_ctrl_keys" }
    ]
},
```

and also the previous two, substituting the `" "`s with `"space"`s.

Any ideas, or is this not possible in Sublime?

Comment: Why the `vim` tag?

Answer (score 0):

Well I found the problem.  I had copied all of the default key bindings for Vintage mode into my user keymap file in order to tinker with them.  I was putting my custom bindings at the top of the file, and in the middle was this binding:

```
{ "keys": [" "], "command": "set_motion", "args": {
    "motion": "vi_move_by_characters",
    "motion_args": {"forward": true, "extend": true, "visual": false },
    "clip_to_line": true },
    "context": [{"key": "setting.command_mode"}]
},
```

Problem solved!